# Decay Old Questions for Google Searches

Tags: feature-request, search, google

The vast majority of common programming questions and answers are now captured on Stack Overflow. This has resulted in Google pushing Stack Overflow results to the top unless you start using advanced search parameters. One of the most common ways to search answers on Stack Overflow is also through Google. This is a problem because for web application development, the jQuery, ASP.NET MVC, Firefox, etc. of 2016 is not the same as 2009.

As such, it would be really nice and "make the internet a better place"(tm) if Stack Overflow would work to decay the indexing that is done by Google. Obviously this would be technically challenging, a search ran in 2016 should not return back 2009 technologies. This may also be a much bigger problem since there is a social aspect to things as well, but it is good to get the conversation started now.

As the commenters have pointed out as well as through down votes, there are issues with this obviously. One of the major concerns is areas where API tags don't have versions associated with them. For example,

[bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-datepicker) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-datepicker))

The older versions of the `datetimepicker` support a `dateFormat` while the newer versions use `format`. This is a fairly tame example, but it underscores the point that older questions make assumptions about versions.

Comment: With many people stuck at jobs where they are *required* to use technology from 2009, I would think this would be a detriment to them.

Comment: I can't imagine how bad this would be for frequently asked questions (e.g [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) unless we prevent them from decaying in some way (e.g tagging them with [faq](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq)).

Comment: Leaving aside whether this is technically possible, this would have way too many false positives and undesired effects.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Conversely, I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap, why should my first hit on Google be a result a question related to the first version of Bootstrap? The API has changed and the result is no longer relevant.

Comment: @rjzii So include a version number in your search query then?

Comment: @Stijn Doesn't that assume that the tagging would be correct?

Comment: @rjzii I'm not sure that's something SO needs to do anything about. Google should (apparently) know that you're looking for the latest version of Bootstrap, know its release date, and tailor the results so that questions from before that date are excluded. I believe there are advanced search operators on both Google and SO that can do that, provided *you* do the (small amount of) research required to find out the release date.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Your response might be worth building into an answer, but part of the problem is that questions may not always be tagged with the correct version. Should something be [tag:bootstrap] or [tag:boostrap3]? Plus, to be blunt, why the hell should I have to do even more work to look something up then I sometimes already have to? In some cases SO takes up most of the first page results so I actually exclude anything from stackoverflow.com from my search so I can look for API documentation better.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Remember, at the end of the say SO is owned by Stack Exchange which is a business. They are in this to make money even though they are trying to make the internet a better place. I'm a customer (ad revenue) given them feedback on something about their product that could be fixed.

Comment: Well, "changed", not "fixed". There's nothing broken

Comment: @Clive I would argue fixed since Google does support not site operators. This would be closer to a non-issue if this worked: `datetimepicker !site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, it doesn't seem related to this discussion. But there's nothing broken, everything is working as designed, so there's nothing to "fix", only a new feature to potentially introduce. Thst was my point, and you appear to agree with it. Otherwise you would have tagged this with "bug" and not "feature request".

Comment: @Clive It's not a "bug" because Google is working correctly. The "feature-request" is for SO to not include questions in their sitemap from over **n** years ago if they have been super-ceded by newer technology. If Google supported additional search operators that allowed filtering it wouldn't be as bit of an issue, but Google does not. Make more sense?

Answer (score 12):

There is no known way as of now to automatically implement "this question contains only obsolete answers" - so no, this is not a feature that can be useful at current level of technology.

What you should do instead is update answers with latest content or adjust them in a way that they properly show up in your searches. Possibly creating canonical answers and closing existing once as duplicates.

Comment: Actually, there is a way of doing it using memory extinction techniques. Use some sort of frequency and age analysis to determine how "fresh" a question is and then adjust the sitemap accordingly

Comment: If we want to address the social aspect of things, as commenters pointed out, some old answers are still valid for older versions of API that may still be in use. Editing the answer to be canonical or closing existing ones would be detrimental to APIs that go through fundamental changes.

Comment: @rjzii - if you have good suggestion to detect "obsolete" content automatically you should post it as separate suggestion - so far all such proposal unfortunately failed to solve it. On second comment - there are many discussions on how to deal with multiple versions - my point is updating existing popular question is better than creating new one.

Comment: I actually do have a fairly decent technique that uses some machine learning and memory extinction but ultimately it would need to be a two pronged solution. One part on the SO UI and the other on the SO sitemap. Part of the problem is that it is a pretty significant chunk of work to do a POC so I'm hesitant to just give it all away for free and you would need a solid POC for it to bubble up to the top on here.